# PHP MySQL - getting "days and hours" left of DATETIME

Tags: php, mysql

I have a MYSQL query that selects all rows that are less than 60 days old.  I would like to display on my PHP page "x days and y hours left".  What's the easiest way to do this?

```
SELECT u.username, u.id, u.score, s.genre, s.songid, s.songTitle, s.timeSubmitted, s.userid, s.insWanted, s.bounty, COUNT(p.songid)
 FROM  songs s
 LEFT JOIN users u
 ON u.id = s.userid
 LEFT JOIN posttracks p
 ON s.songid = p.songid
 WHERE paid=1 AND s.timeSubmitted >= ( CURDATE() - INTERVAL 60 DAY )
 GROUP BY s.timeSubmitted DESC
 LIMIT 15
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In PHP try something along these lines when looping over your rows:

```
$then = strtotime($futureDateAsString);
$diff = $then - time();
echo sprintf("%s days and %s hours left", date('z', $diff), date('G', $diff));
```

Comment: `echo sprintf()` is an "antipattern". There is absolutely no reason that anyone should ever write `echo sprintf()` in any code for any reason -- it should be `printf()` every time.

Answer (score 1):

Try [`TIMEDIFF()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_timediff).

Comment: [Are answers that just contain links elsewhere really "good answers"?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8231/352329)